# when I run a simple program in Junit, it is giving me this error. I already inserted jar files and configured my build path

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/ConfigurationParameters
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.(JUnit5TestLoader.java:34)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:642)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createRawTestLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:371)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.createLoader(RemoteTestRunner.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.defaultInit(RemoteTestRunner.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.init(RemoteTestRunner.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
... 13 more

Comment: Which jar files? Which one of them contains the org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters class?

Comment: org.junit file @nitind

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example please.